# Uncollateralized cross currency swap valuation

Tags: interest-rate-swap, cross-currency-basis

I want to value an **uncollateralized** cross-currency swap to exchange **EURIBOR 6M** for **JIBAR 3M** (Johannesburg Interbank Average Rate).

I have a few questions:

1. What discount curves should I use?
2. From which curve should I infer forward rates for each leg?

Thanks for your help.

For the first question, I think I should be using the EURO 6M swap curve and a basis discount curve for *JIBAR vs EUR*. However, such basis curves do not necessarily exist on Bloomberg or other financial data providers.

Is it correct to imply the basis curve *JIBAR vs EUR* from the two following basis curves: *JIBAR vs USD* and *EUR vs USD*?